# Connections of Voltage Comparator Circuit with LM2903

Tags: analog, comparator

I am planning to use the [LM2903](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0006493411_1-2542964.pdf) and a [P channel MOSFET](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/NTGS3441T1_D-1813806.pdf) to prevent discharging of a LiPo battery below 3.3V.

Here is my current schematic, where 3V3OUT is the output from 3.3V buck boost converter, BATT+ is the battery voltage, and +3V3 is the final output:
[image]

Do I have the IN+ and IN- pins correct? I want the transistor to be turned on if BATT+ is greater than 3.3V, so I think that means the output should be a logic 0. The datasheet states: [image]

but I am unsure as to whether that means that the output will be high or low if IN+ is greater than IN-.

Comment: You probably used those square box symbols because that's what KiCAD or whatever schematic/PCB package you're using had.  However, you'll get a better response here if you use standard schematic symbols for your questions.  It takes an extra level of effort to decipher this kind of schematic.

Comment: I use KiCad and never found those box symbols, what library are they in? I agree with the standard symbols. Simple trick with comparators using the - as the reference and the + as the input the output will be high if the + is positive to the - and conversely - if it is less. You may want to add a little hysteresis as it will oscillate at the switchover point.

Answer (score 0):

The IN+ & IN- polarities are ok. However, I am afraid, your comparator will not work because your input common mode is not proper. You need to feed a lower input common mode voltage by giving a divided version of the voltages to IN+ & IN- or use some other comparator that allows you to use a higher input common mode voltage.

Edit: what about chattering of the comparator output? If you are worried about it consider adding hysteresis.